# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in OkHttpClient.Builder() after updating from retrofit 2.6.2 to retrofit 2.9.0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

Earlier I was using **retrofit version 2.6.2** in my project to call an api service and everything was working fine. I am creating a custom `Interceptor` to add the `api key` to the header of every request.

NetworkInterceptor.kt

```
class NetworkInterceptor() : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        var request = chain.request()
            request = request.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID ${NetworkConfig.CLIENT_ID}")
                .build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

I updated the retrofit library to version `2.9.0` and after updating to **retrofit version `2.9.0`** I am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` in the line `OkHttpClient.Builder()` while adding the `Interceptor` to the `Retrofit.Builder()`.

Api.kt

```
interface Api {

    @GET("photos")
    suspend fun getPhotos(
        @Query("page") pageNumber: Int,
        @Query("per_page") pageSize: Int,
        @Query("order_by") orderBy: String
    ) : Response<List<Photo>>

    @GET("photos/random")
    suspend fun getRandomPhoto() : Response<Photo>

    companion object{
        operator fun invoke(
            networkInterceptor: NetworkInterceptor
        ) : Api{

            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()    //java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
                .addInterceptor(networkInterceptor)
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(NetworkConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(Api::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I don't know how to solve this error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your OkHttp version?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I am not using specific dependency for OkHttp, I am using the default version that comes with retrofit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the compile options inside android block of your app level `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
...

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to rebuild your project. Make sure your project is using the latest OkHttp library 3.14.9.

Comment: The latest version of OkHttp is 4.7.2

Comment: @SaurabhThorat Rebuilding the project doesn't help either.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat 3.14.* is Java-based, 4.x is Kotlin-based

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, resolved after updating OkHttp library 3.14.9 from 3.10.0